# How do I get gitlab api to list the releases for my project?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

curl command...

```
> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my-private-token"
> "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-user-name/api/v4/projects/my-project-id/releases"
```

response...

> You are being [redirected](https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in).

I am sure it is the wrong url but not sure how to correct it...

gitlab docs example bellow..

```
> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: gDybLx3yrUK_HLp3qPjS"
> "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/releases"
```

gitlab doc for this...

> https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/releases/index.html#list-releases

Comment: does the token have right scopes ("api") or at least "read_api"?

Comment: yes for testing purposes I ticked the api box, which I believe allows all api access.

Comment: Why is there `gitlab-user-name` in your curl command when there isn't that in the gitlab example?

Comment: the exact example does not work, I believe gitlab.example.com is where you put your specific url.

Comment: sorry, what's `gitlab-user-name` in the url?

Comment: that would be my git lab username or your git lab username for your account.

Answer (score 0):

The “you’re being redirected” message means it’s an authentication/authorization issue, not a problem with the uri or project.

Double check your access token has the correct scopes, isn’t revoked or expired, and that the user who owns the token has access to the project.